# Solving Android 4+ dynamic JS linkage problems on PhoneGap 1.4.1

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am experiencing the oft-noted problem of accessing JS files with PhoneGap on Android 4.0+. This is a nasty webview bug that affects PhoneGap apps fatally. If I try to dynamically load a script, e.g.

```
$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="app/android.js"></script>');
```

Android 4.0+ will bork on a 404, aka "chromium error -6" -- it cannot resolve the url. This has catastrophic effects on XHR requests. The problem is outlined in this thread and a kind user has posted a patch for PhoneGap 1.7:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

I have tried this patch and it works. What I am wondering is if anything can be done for PhoneGap 1.4.1. Upgrading my production build to 1.7 at this point is not a viable solution and I imagine others are in a similar position with this major Android bug. It's worth noting that even PhoneGap 1.8.1 hasn't integrated the above patch.

Has anyone been able to resolve this issue for PhoneGap 1.4.1?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem of loading js dynamically in ICS and solved below way :

1. Read contents JS file using java code and java returns contents of js file as a string
2. In js get data from Java code and executed code globally using globalEval